# Where should the code for creating Dash apps be run?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am completely new to Dash, and am attempting to create a Dash app for hosting some visualizations I made with Plotly. I have only ever written code in Jupyter notebooks, and have tried JupyterDash, but get connection errors when I try to run the code for any example/tutorial apps. What should I be using instead of a Jupyter notebook to create a Dash app? Any suggestions for resources for complete beginners would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to have this app set up. If running it locally, accessible from your own machine only, is fine, then you can run it from the command line with something like:

`python /path/to/my/app.py`

If you want it to be available on the internet, then you're getting into much different territory. Perhaps the simplest way would be to run your app with something like Github and Heroku, although I haven't done that myself so you'd need to search for a tutorial. Beyond that is some heavy lifting with things like purchasing a domain, hosting setup, and more.